# Plugins fail to update: Download failed. A valid URL was not provided

Tags: plugins, updates, nginx

We recently moved a client's website from DigitalOcean $5 droplet LEMP stack to a friend's private server to minimise expenses. It supposed to fly faster but instead of started dropping off some weird errors for some reason and works really slow even comparing to the previous instance. Unfortunately, the server administrator is either not quite sure what's the cause. Someone on a forum suggested changing the permissions of the plugin folder to 775, however, I'm very sceptical that it would help with that.

When we try out to update around 20 plugins it ends up with this error: `504 Gateway Time-out nginx`

Updating one plugin:

```
The update process is starting. This process may take a while on some hosts, so please be patient.

Enabling Maintenance mode…
Updating Plugin Contact Form 7 (1/1)

Downloading update from http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/contact-form-7.5.1.7.zip…

An error occurred while updating Contact Form 7: Download failed. A valid URL was not provided.

Disabling Maintenance mode…

All updates have been completed.

Return to Plugins page | Return to WordPress Updates page
```

Comment: I agree, I don't see what file permissions has in relation to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deployed WordPress on Kubernetes. Once I update host mapping it starts working.

```
      hostAliases:
      - ip: "66.155.40.202"
        hostnames:
          - "api.wordpress.org"
      - ip: "198.143.164.250"
        hostnames:
          - "downloads.wordpress.org"
```

On the server we can do same way in `/etc/hosts` file for linux:

```
66.155.40.202 api.wordpress.org
198.143.164.250 downloads.wordpress.org
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use this code in functions.php to avoid ssl check :

```
add_filter( 'http_request_args', function ( $args ) {

    $args['reject_unsafe_urls'] = false;
    
    return $args;
}, 999 );
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll try it out when will get access to the server.

Comment: Did this work @organic ?

Comment: This has not worked for me.

Comment: Hi mate, it appears to be that guy just limited resources on his server and it encountered this issue. After a while he's given us a bit more resources therefore the error disappeared.

What's you stack right now? PHP, MySQL, Nginx versions. Actually a few websites work pretty fine on my own server with PHP 8, MySQL 8, Nginx 1.21. Try to update && upgrade your server then bring new packages. I guess it should work out well :)